# DC Motor parameter in simscape

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I'm here because I'm trying to implement a DC motor model in simscape. I'm having trouble matching the motor specifications, after filling the block with the parameters taken from the datasheet the output is not what I was expecting. For instance the speed with load is rated at 4310rpm, the output of my model after converting rad/s to rmp is only ~0.6rpm

I'm thinking about some wrong conversion, but can't find the issue by myself. Following the model implementation and motor parameters.

- [motor parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qe4Q.png)
- [motor scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ1Gn.png)
- [block configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7i0F.png)
- [system implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRIgE.png)
- [simulation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoSik.png)

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Ok, I've solved it by replacing the revolute joint. There was some parameter causing this problem, unfortunately, I didn't find out which was.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.